# Computer does not boot after Driver Verifier: unable to use it

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-driver-verifier

I ran Driver Verifier, selected all drivers and reboot.

Now computer doesn't boot. It enters diagnostic screen with many icons, some of them suggesting to reinstall Windows.

Is it possible to recover?

**UDPATE**

[Driver Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-verifier) is a built-in feature of Microsoft.

**UPDATE 2**

Finally I got the following regularities:

1) If I select all drivers in Driver Verifier, I get windows just not boot with black screen or entering diagnostic mode.

2) If I select part of drivers, then I get BSOD with `DRIVER_VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION`. I tried to sord drivers by vendor name and select all before Microsoft and all after Microsoft (excluding MS).

Looks like by some reason I can use Driver Verifier at all!

Comment: maybe some AHCI incompatible drivers were installed

Comment: Could you please elaborate regarding exactly what the *"Driver Verifier"* actually is?  I assume it is a third-party utility for analyzing and/or updating your device drivers.  To be perfectly honest, I tend to avoid software utilities like those.  While they could potentially help in some respects, they have also been known to cause major problems (like this one).  I'm not sure that have very latest drivers for every device is important enough to trust a potentially unstable software program.

Comment: @Run5k no it is Microsoft's, see my update

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Safe Mode. Download [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) (I never tried Autoruns in safe mode but there is no reason it shouldn't work). Open Autoruns, go to **Options** and check **Hide Microsoft Entries**. It should hide all Microsoft (and, thus, Windows) entries. Now, uncheck everything you see (you can move to **Drivers** tab to disable drivers too). After disabling everything, try to boot Windows normally.

[image: Autoruns]