# How to boot Windows 10 to safe mode from cold?

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode

My computer doesn't boot, so no any methods including magic clicking on running computer are not applicable.

So, I have turned off computer on my desk.

How to boot it into safe mode?

**UPDATE**

I found experimentally, that to enter safe mode, one should have failed boot for TWO subsequent times. After that Windows goes to diagnostic screen, where, rather deep, there is an icon to initiate Safe Mode.

Would accept this as an answer.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit? Why your computer doesn't boot? And if doesn't, how can it boot into safe mode!

Comment: Safe mode is a special mode, when many components are not loaded. Not-loaded components can have bugs or be corrupted. This is how it can be that computer can boot in safe mode but can't boot in normal mode. Please google about this.

Comment: I know very well what safe mode is. So, by "my computer doesn't boot", do you actually mean that when you start your computer you see Windows loading but it shuts down (or maybe crash) and doesn't complete booting process?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't complete booting, but tries to. It crashes into BSOD or hangs.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://superuser.com/questions/948481/how-do-you-start-windows-10-in-safe-mode) can help you boot into safe mode. BTW, can you just provide us with the details of BSOD so we can understand the reason behind crash.

Comment: Thanks, it's incredible. My problem is here: http://superuser.com/questions/1149056/computer-does-not-boot-after-driver-verifier

Answer (score 0):

To boot into safe mode without specifying in the Boot tab of the System Configuration window (msconfig) before restarting, you simply turn on the machine while holding the `F8` key.

If your computer does not boot, I do not know how you are going to get into safe mode, though.

Comment: Pressing `F8` does not help. It was working several versions back I guess, and does not work anymore.

Answer (score -3):

Can you get to a CMD Prompt?  If so run following command:
BCDEDIT /SET {DEFAULT} BOOTMENUPOLICY LEGACY

This will allow f8 to make use of legacy menus that will include booting to Safe Mode.  After all is complete, you can use the following command (or leave it):
BCDEDIT /SET {DEFAULT} BOOTMENUPOLICY STANDARD